# In-app full unlock features without internet connection

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have an app which has a trial and a full version. Both are in the same apk (same app in the store).

I want the user to be promped after `N` days for the full unluck with a purchase dialog.

I read about `in-app billing`, but my app doesn't require internet connection to work and I found some app in the store not using this permission for the full unlock payment.

What I want is:

- Full unlock feature on my app after `N` days (and i'm ok on how to achieve it with shared preferences)
- `In-app` payment without `internet permission`
- `Purchase history` feature, because if someone buy the app and for any reason he has to uninstall it, I don't wanna him to be asked to pay again.

How can  I get those goals?

Thanks all.

Comment: Based on the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-permission) you don't need to add internet permission to your app because you rely on the google play services which has that permission. You just add `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />` and implement things as usual.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I found another SO answer saying I would need it and I was confused. Thanks for the clarification! About the history, can I query google play servicies for this or I need other features? Thanks